# Android GridView Height Autofill the Remaing Space

Tags: android, android-gridview

Is it possible for a GridView to auto adjust to occupy the remaining empty space of its parent layout? If yes how ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It is possible.

Let's consider following xml,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  //First View or layout
  <RelativeLayout            
        android:id="@+id/first_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#000">
  </RelativeLayout>

  //Second View or layout
  <RelativeLayout             
        android:id="@+id/second_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first_layout"
        android:background="#8b3737">
  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity,

```
 RelativeLayout layout_one=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.first_layout);
 RelativeLayout layout_two=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.second_layout);
```

when you set,

```
 layout_one.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then the second Layout/View will occupy the whole parent space.

NOTE: I took relative layouts for examples. It can be any view. But the parent should be a RelativeLayout.

If you want second layout to be hidden and first layout should fill parent,

Then the XML will be,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  //First View or layout
  <RelativeLayout            
        android:id="@+id/first_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/second_layout"
        android:background="#000">
  </RelativeLayout>

  //Second View or layout
  <RelativeLayout             
        android:id="@+id/second_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#8b3737">
  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when you set,

```
 layout_two.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then the first Layout/View will occupy the whole parent space.

NOTE: At least one Layout/View should have static height(in this case).

I hope it will help you.

All the best.